# Finding the Difference in DateTimeFields

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to find if two DateTimeFields are greater than 2 days difference in a template.  Is this possible to do in a template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this inside a template.  You could first calculate the day difference in the view, but I doesn't sound like that's what you want.

The easiest way to do this *inside a template* would be to write a custom template filter.  (Custom template filters are quite a bit easier than creating custom tags, by the way.)

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters

Answer (score 1):

Calculation should not be done in the template. Calculate in the view and pass it in as a context variable.